# loading custom gstreamer plugin raises gst.ElementNotFoundError

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer

I'm trying to set `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable before loading custom gstreamer plugin in an integration test, so I need to change `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` programmatically.

But without `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` set in shell, `gst.element_factory_make` fails.

I'm using gstreamer-0.10, python2.6 and linux 3.2.0 (debian 6).

Example:

```
import gst, os
os.environ['GST_PLUGIN_PATH'] = '/tmp'
print gst.element_factory_make('myelem')
```

Without `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` set in shell:

```
$ export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=
$ ./gstpathtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gstpathtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    print gst.element_factory_make('myelem')
gst.ElementNotFoundError: myelem
```

With `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` set in shell:

```
$ GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/tmp ./gstpathtest.py
/MyElem:myelem0 (__main__.MyElem)
```

or with `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` exported in shell:

```
$ export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/tmp
$ ./gstpathtest.py
/MyElem:myelem0 (__main__.MyElem)
```

When run with `GST_DEBUG=6` I noticed that `myelem` gets created but is immediately unref-ed and destroyed, which is probably the cause of the error.

I even tried to add the path to `os.environ['PATH']`, or directly to `sys.path` but it didn't change anything.

My main question is: am I doing something wrong on *python-level* (and what exactly) or does it indicate some bug in the *myelem* plugin itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, `gst.registry.scan_path` works:

```
import gst
gst.registry_get_default().scan_path('/tmp')
print gst.element_factory_make('myelem')
```

Comment: how i will set in ios

Comment: @DURGESHKUMAR - I'm not familiar with iOS, and since this is not very popular question, you probably won't get any help from anyone here. I think you should create new question specifically for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, stupid me - if I set `os.environ['GST_PLUGIN_PATH']` before importing `gst`, everything works as expected.